# Trying to dismiss view controller through callback code block, but getting exception

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was trying to dismiss the presented view controller from the callback code block like below.

```
MyBViewController *bvc = [[MyBViewController alloc] init];

bvc.callBack = ^(void){
   NSLog(@"Dismiss");
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
};
```

But it is throwing EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception. In the exception stack it seems like it is in [MyBViewController callback];

I even tried calling another local method to dismiss that would fire after 1.0 second. But got the same error.

Is not possible to dismiss through callback block like this? Kindly let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Is "Dismiss" getting printed in the console?

Comment: Finally figured out, i made the callback property on the MyBViewController to 'copy' previously it was 'assign'. Then it worked.

Comment: Glad you did it! Post an answer and accept it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i figured that out. I was having callback property on MyBViewController as 'assign'. I fixed that by changing to 'copy'. Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your callback is probably being called when bvc is deallocated.

Without seeing the rest of your code I am just assuming that your callback function is called after the function of where bvc is allocated completes and ARC probably cleans it up. Then the callback is fired on a deallocated object and is how you would get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS. You should try making bvc a property or iVar so it doesn't die early.

Comment: I tried it, but still EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Wondering how the same self dismiss... works when done through delegate callback.

Answer (score 0):

As developer.apple.com sais: "The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view controller it presented. If you call this method on the presented view controller itself, however, it automatically forwards the message to the presenting view controller."
You may use `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];` inside `MyBViewController` without using any blocks. Hope this will help you.